# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle] (Followup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, observable

Ok so I finally figured out which part of my code is causing the exception. You can read the initial post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099156/ns-error-xpc-bad-convert-js-could-not-convert-javascript-argument-arg-0-nsidom) The code in the initial post is missing the part which is actually causing the exception (the manual subscription to the `viewPortData` observable). Apparently, I'm doing it wrong somehow... Here's the code:

```
self.viewPortData = ko.observable();
self.viewPortData.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    var viewPort = $('#metro-view-port');
    if (viewPort && newValue) {
        self.fadeInOut(viewPort, newValue);
    }
});

self.fadeInOut = function (domObject, newContent) {
    if (newContent) {
        var currentContent = domObject.html();
        if (currentContent) {
            var wrappedContent = $(currentContent);
            wrappedContent.fadeOut(400, function () {
                wrappedContent.empty();
                domObject.html(newContent).hide().fadeIn(400);
            });
        } else {
            domObject.html(newContent).hide().fadeIn(400);
        }
    }
};
```

So where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmym715/J2pp6/) using your code from this post and the previous post, and it works as it should.

However, I'm only returning a simple `<div>` tag to populate the HTML of the `metro-view-port` `<div>`.

My best guess is that the HTML that you're returning is the problem.

My advice to you is to first confirm this by reducing the HTML returned to something very simple, and then *gradually* reintroduce the intended code until you find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The same error occurred to me. The problem was caused because the HTML had comments on it. Something like:

```
<!-- Some Comment goes here -->
<div>
    ...
</div>
```

To fix that, without changing the HTML, you need to wrap the HTML with something else, so you pass only one element to jQuery:

```
var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
div.innerHTML = nativeHtml;

var $html = $( div );
```

Comment: confirmed - when I removed html comment from the code to be appended, the error has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Flip your fadeIn(400) to a show().

It is simpler for jQuery to do the math for.... I think that it can't get computed style of the elements due to some floats inside it or something.

I had the same problem..... but after some research I got to here (DAMMET I LOST THE TAB - it was a jQuery bug report anyway ) and realised what needed to be fiddeled with to fix it.

In my code I swapped out fadeIn() to show() so it isn't to do with the animation

you would have thought that without the animation the problem wouldn't be prevalent either - but it is.

try slideDown(0 if your still after an animation, it might not work but its worth a  pop.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was in old versions of jQuery. Try to change .hide() to .css('display', 'none')

Answer (score 1):

According to [this jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12462), the problem may have to do with newline characters and whitespace text nodes in your HTML. In my case, I was taking a template like this one:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template">
  <div>
    <h2>Important stuff</h2>
  </div>
</script>
```

And parsing it like this:

```
var currentContent = $.parseHTML($('#myTemplate').html());
```

So I ended up with a bunch of text nodes representing the newline and whitespace characters in the original HTML template. Probably something similar has happened to you.

To fix this, I stripped out the newlines and whitespaces like so:

```
$('#myTemplate').html().replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/>\s+</g, '><').trim();
```

Hope that helps someone!